# How to determine what type of interruption caused applicationWillResignActive to be called

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I determine what type of interruptions triggered the applicationWillResignActive call?

Comment: Your question is not clear..

Comment: What types of interruptions do you need to distinguish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. You get notified that there **is** an interruption, but that's it.